# lightning connect and stored procedure

Tags: lightning-connect

Say I have a stored proc and two tables in a SQL Server DB.
I want to expose the data in the tables to SF. That I can achieve by creating a oData service in, say, .NET and expose the tables. Lightning connect will use the endpoint exposed by the oData service and create two External objects one for each table.

Now, I also want the functionality of the stored proc be available in SF.

-Can I expose the SP as a oData service and consume that in Salesforce via Lightning connect?

-If not what are the options available to me reuse the Stored proc functionality using Lightning Connect?

Answer (score 1):

I had opened a ticket with Salesforce and heard back from them:

"We got an update from product management team regarding the question. They informed that as of now it is not possible to consume stored procedure via Lightning Connect. It is actually easier to use Apex callout for that kind of application integration."

Answer (score 0):

The Social Foundry has a similar product. You may want to check them out and see if it is a good fit.

Full disclosure I work for the Social Foundry.

Comment: Thanks. I checked out Social Foundry. It is a useful wrapper to expose and invoke DB operations/resources as services and plays well in that space. However one advantage using Lightning Connect is, once the connection is established with the oData Service it automatically generates Salesforce objects. This is useful because you get the out-of-box salesforce functionality for free and is easy to integrate with other salesforce objects and resources. It is sad that stored procedure integration is missing! Why not simply make the return object from the SP also as a local SF object??